# When to use escape and escaped?

Tags: british-english

A man trying to escape from deadly machine which is about to explode and at the same time victim saw that man is in dangerous situation but victim didn't see whether that man died or not after the machine exploded. 
Thing is whether to use escape or escaped.

Comment: Additional context and examples wouold be helpful here.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. Your question is rather unclear. *Escape* is a noun or a verb. *Escaped* is an adjective or the preterite of the verb. How you would use one or the other would depend on how you phrase the sentence.

Comment: Are you asking if you should use *a man trying to* ***escape*** or *a man trying to* ***escaped***? If not, you need to be be clearer about what you're asking.

Comment: Yes that's what I asked?

Answer (score 1):

One could say or write

> - The man escaped.
> - The man was able to escape.
> - We don't know if the man escaped, because the witness could not see.
> - It isn't known if the man could escape or not.
> - The man failed to escape.
> - The man was unable to escape.
> - Had the man escaped, he would have been seen afterwards.

Many other variants using either "escape" or "escaped" are possible, depending on what meaning is intended, and whose point of view the sentence is beign written from.

Comment: No sir it was just an example and  created myself to clarify that word